# The foreign key id cannot loaded in drop-down list in Django temlate

Tags: python-3.x, database, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

In the `entry.id` cannot fetch the data from table. And I also save the selected option to store in another table. How can I do this?

**register.html**

```
<form method="POST"> 
<select name="item_id"> 
{% for entry in items %} 
<option value="{{ entry.id }}">{{ entry.name }}</option> 
{% endfor %} 
</select> 
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass entry name instaed of option tag

```
<form method="POST"> 
<select name="item_id"> 
{% for entry in items %} 

{{ entry.name }}

{% endfor %} 
</select> 
</form>
```

It will take option tag automatically